# Name field in oauth_access_tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I use laravel passport for authentication. By default it generates some tables after installation. One of them is 'oauth_access_tokens' table.
This table contains a column named 'name'.
What is for this column?
I have the following function and do not know what to use in name field:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['user_name' => $request->user_name, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('xxx')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
        }
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
```

Columns of oauth_access_tokens: id, user_id, client_id, name, scopes, revoked, created_at, updated_at, expires_at.

Answer (score 0):

In `oauth_access_tokens` the column named `name` is just descriptive name for the token. It can be anything.